# Nodejs Cannot find module '../build/Release/canvas'

Tags: node.js, node-canvas

I installed cairo, and [node-canvas](https://www.npmjs.com/package/canvas). I tried everything, but still can't find module.

```
sudo apt-get install libcairo2-dev
sudo npm install canvas
sudo npm install canvas -g
```

If I run `require('canvas')`, I get this error:

```
Error: Cannot find module '../build/Release/canvas'
    at Function._resolveFilename (module.js:332:11)
    at Function._load (module.js:279:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:354:17)
    at require (module.js:370:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/tomas/node_modules/canvas/lib/bindings.js:2:18)
    at Module._compile (module.js:441:26)
    at Object..js (module.js:459:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:348:32)
    at Function._load (module.js:308:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:354:17)
```

I use Ubuntu linux

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check if the module is in your node_module directory and if it is, try to require the full path like `require('./node_modules/canvas');`

Comment: You got the module in that directory ?
Check https://github.com/LearnBoost/node-canvas/issues/137

Comment: yes. `test.js` is in the same directory as the `node_modules`, and canvas directory is inside the node_modules

Comment: canvas module is the worst of all, never had this many problems with anything in my life...been trying to do this for like 3 days...it's all over the place. putting direct path from c:... worked though..

Comment: For me I did `npm clean-install` and it worked.

Comment: it seems like a directory issue

Answer (score 23):

*I spent a lot of time to resolve this issue ...*

Use `npm uninstall canvas` and then install using `npm i canvas`.

Comment: I was so skeptical this would work, but I thought I must try it.  -- Solved my problem! thanks!

Comment: `npm install canvas@latest` works too

Comment: Is there a way to solve this from root? I'm constantly npm installing in that folder and it gets annoying after some time.

Comment: @Santiago you can try `rm -rf node_modules` and  `npm cache clean –force` . Then do `npm install`.

Answer (score 10):

It seemed like the `install` script of `canvas` haven't been called in my case, too. Instead of deleting the lock file I just called the script manually which solved the issue in my case (at least temporarily).

Therefore, if the `canvas` package has been installed already, go to */node_modules/canvas/* and run `npm run install` which creates the build directory.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem. The issue was that the `install` script for `node-canvas` never got executed, which is why the `build` folder was missing.

In my case, removing the `yarn.lock` file was the solution, as it skipped the `node-canvas` package installation for some reason. Once I let `npm` take care of the packages, it successfully installed `node-canvas`, ran the `install` script and the build folder showed up again.

Comment: I had a similar problem, I had disabled install-scripts. Re-enabling them resolved my issue.

Answer (score 2):

Problem here looks like 
1. Your node modules are installed in a different location But the node.js runtime is searching for it in a different place. Check the NODE_PATH and see if this is the case.

Refer the module loading explained in http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_loading_from_the_global_folders

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

- Delete node_modules/ folder
- Run dependency installations (`npm install`)
- Use a different Node version

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Same problem in my nextjs application. In my case. I installed `react-pdf` package then this problem happened.

My resolve: Just Notify webapck to ignore the `canvas` module

Add the following webpack options in `next.config.js`

```js
const nextConfig = {
  webpack(config){
    config.externals.push('canvas')
    return config
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case:

```
rm -rf node_modules
rm package-lock.json
npm install
```

:D

Comment: Easiest solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Next.js or Next.js 14, you may need to add the following to your next.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
 webpack: (config) => {
   config.resolve.alias.canvas = false;

   return config;
 },
}
```

ref: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-pdf

this is work for me

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem but I used canvas-prebuilt which is a drop-in replacement for canvas and I fixed it for doing this:
**npm install -g node-gyp** and then **node-gyp rebuild** in the terminal

Answer (score -2):

```
sudo apt-get install libpixman-1-dev libcairo2-dev libpangocairo-1.0-0 libpango1.0-dev libgif-dev  libjpeg-dev
```

If use ubuntu，try install above lib then install canvas.work fine for me。

If you use cnpm install the canvas. try npm.